# What is this low-growing weed with narrow stems and yellow flowers, and how do I exterminate it?

Tags: grass, weed-control, weeds, lawn

My lawn is "Blue Couch" (Digitaria didactyla). It's a pretty hardy grass and tolerates most weed killers that you can use on couch grass (Cynodon dactylon, Bermuda).

What is this creeping weed that is taking over my lawn and how do I kill it? It is aggressive and so low that mowing it achieves nothing.

I'm in Queensland, Australia. Warm climate.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The weed appears to be Lotononis bainesii. This species was introduced to the country as a fodder legume. To the best of our knowledge it shouldn’t present any problems to children or pets. Apparently, it is susceptible to acifluorfen, bentazone, 2,4-D and 2,4-DB.

Comment: Number one do not allow these flower to seed!  Hack, cut them down!  Roundup is more than enough to control this weed.  I'd get a weed wacker going right now and top these weeds.  Now.  Then spray with glyphosate.  Is this a gravel patch?

Comment: And consider a large scale weed control. As you see, it produce long stolons, so a lively population near you can invade your garden quickly, at will.

Comment: bentazone smashed it in one pass

Comment: but I'll do two!